# Override parent::function

Tags: php, class, oop, overriding

Hello I have classes with functions

```
class A{
    static function a(){
        return 'aaa';
    }
}
class B extends A{
    static function b(){
        //some code
        return parent::a();
        //some code
    }
}
```

Now i need to write class 'C', I need change method 'a' to return another thing, but not want override B::b() function, because it's really big, and working normal.

```
class C extends D{
    static function b(){
        return parent::b();
    }
}

class D extends B{
    static function a(){
        return 'ddd';
    }

}
C::b() //return aaa, but I need ddd
```

Comment: Why are you calling `parent::a` from `b`? Why not `self::a`/`static::a`? And why is all this `static` to begin with?

Comment: As deceze said, use self::a() instead of parent::a() in B class

Comment: classes A and B not mine, and I can't change them. And they are static, because they are static methods :)

Comment: I know, I can override function b in my classes, copy the code and change parent::b() to self::b(), but really don't want, because if in future they will change their function b, my code will not update.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to have `//some code` after `return parent::a();`. Nothing after `return` gets executed.

Comment: Even if you could do this, how would something in `class D` affect `C::b()`?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this. There's no way to say "Call the parent function, but make it call something else when it calls `parent::a()`"

Comment: @Barmar it's not real code, it's simplified for explaining, I know that after return nothing will executed.

Comment: @Barmar class C extends  D

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I wanted to see if you noticed the obvious.
In your example, you have `C::b()` which returns `parent::b` coming from `B`, not `D`.  You wanted the return from `D::a` which would be `C::a()`